# arcpy.ListDatasets() returns emtpy list

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcpy, enterprise-geodatabase

I'm having trouble getting the ListDatasets (or any of the list functions) to return anything but an empty list when pointed at our SDE geodatabase, but the same code works for a file geodatabase. I searched how to connect to the SDE GDB and I can't see a mistake. I know the connection file works, I can open it with Catalog and log in just fine and it has a saved password with it. I'm at a loss, which means I have probably done something stupid. Help?

```
# Import arcpy module
import arcpy
from arcpy import env

env.workspace = r"F:Replicated Data\Auto_Extract_Connection.sde"

datasetList = arcpy.ListDatasets()

print datasetList

env.workspace =  r"F:\Replicated Data\Gatekeeper_Extract.gdb"

datasetList = arcpy.ListDatasets()

print datasetList
```

Returns:

[]

[u'ElectricDataset', u'CPUDataset', u'TransmissionDataset']

Comment: Have you visually confirmed that there are actual [feature datasets](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//002300000001000000) that reside in "Auto_Extract_Connection.sde"?  As opposed to just standalone [feature classes](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//003n00000005000000)?  And of course that you have permissions to view data in "Auto_Extract_Connection.sde"?

Comment: Yes. The connection file points at our test database, plenty of datasets in there to look at. As for permissions, I can run arcpy.Exists() and look for a known feature class and it returns success.

Comment: I am not sure if it is just a typo or not but you forgot the '\' in your first workspace path after the F:

Comment: Thank You dklassen and @Luke! See? I told you I was being stupid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your path is missing a backslash after the drive letter: change F:Replicated to F:\Replicated.